# Is there a way to assume a default value for old data on a newly created custom dimension on GA/Data studio?

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I have several events in google analytics and they are displayed on a dashboard in DataStudio. I have created a new flow on my application that has the same events as a previous flow, but I would like to distinguish which events were generated in one flow vs the other. So, I created a custom dimension (flow) that I can associate with all my events `Flow 1` and `Flow 2`. That works fine. The problem is that if I add a filter on data studio with this custom dimension, there is not a way to assume that all the events without this dimension are flow 1.

I know that I cannot update past analytics data, but is there a way to when I click on the filter `Flow 1` it filters by both `Flow 1` + everything without this dimension?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a filter that would be “does not equal flow 2”. Therefore any data left either has no flow attached or is flow 1

Comment: I thought about that, but I cannot add this to a filter control on data studio, right? I would have to maybe duplicate my page.

Comment: You can create two segments in google analytics that is does not equal flow 2 and equals flow 2. Then use the filter control to control which segment to look at in data studio